# capture string patter with letf and right spans not including this pattern

Tags: regex, pcre

I don't manage to find a solution to my regexp problem.

Here is text :
`My text is so interesting, depending "interesting" meaning of course.`

I'd like to match all strings containing for example `interest.{3}` and spreading left and right as much as possible without matching `interest.{3}` again. So I'd like to have these matches :

`My text is so interesting, depending "interestin`

`nteresting, depending "interesting" meaning of course.`

Is there any way to achieve this with PCRE regexp ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you please clarify what "spreading left and right as much as possible without matching `interest{.3}` again" means? Your example is not helpful.

Comment: I want to match the pattern `interest{.3}`and get as much as context as possible on left and right of that pattern, but without having that pattern being present in right and left contexts.

Comment: @arnaudbey `interest{.3}` isn't a valid regex pattern. Did you mean `interest.{3}` (that is, "interest" followed by three characters) ?

Comment: yep, sorry for the typo, i meant interest.{3}

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = 'Here is text : My text is so interesting, depending "interesting" meaning of course.'

s = text
while True:
    m = re.search(r'(?:.*?)i(nterest\w{2})(\w)(?:(?<!i\1)(?!=\2).)*', s)
    if not m:
        break
    print(m[0])
    s = s[m.span(1)[0]:]
```

Prints:

```
Here is text : My text is so interesting, depending "interestin
nteresting, depending "interesting" meaning of course.
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/2DW4Wc)

```
(?:.*?)i(nterest\w{2})(\w)(?:(?<!i\1)(?!=\2).)*
```

The string we are looking for is broken up into pieces:

1. 'i' matches i
2. `(nterest\w{2})` Capture group 1 -> `interest` plus the first two word characters of our match.
3. `(\w)` Capture group 2 -> the third and final character of our match.

Then we scan one character at a time as long as the preceding characters are not `i` plus capture group 1 and the next character is not capture group 2:

4. `(?:(?<!i\1)(?!=\2).)*`

Then we use the location of capture group 1 to determine where the next scan should begin.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Booboo's answer, here is a regex that works for this. Interesting thing is that this doesn't work in Java but very well in Python. One difference here is that there is no backreference allowing `interesting` and `interested.` to be considered as matches in the same text. You can try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Zo9wDd/2). It is working there.

```
(?=((^|interest.{3}).*?interest.{3}.*?(interest.{3}|$)))
```

**Explanation**

- Let `X` = `interest.{3}`. Then, this regex reduces to a more general `(?=((^|X).*?X.*?(X|$)))`.
- Also, I have considered that saying "to the right and the left of X" is the same as "X in the middle of a span" (with some reservations, of course).

Based on that:

1. The whole regex is a positive lookahead with capturing groups `(?=(regex))`. This means that though the match will be made against `X`, it will not move its position to the end of the current match (to look for the next match). Instead, it will incrementally move character by character in the string picking up all matches owing to capturing groups. (However, in Java it seems to be working differently.)
2. The capturing group `(^|X)` allows a match for the start of the text or `X` (the boundary case).
3. The second `X` is to allow for the presence of `X` in the middle of the "span".
4. The capturing group `(X|$)`, like the first one in point (2), is to allow for the boundary `X` which may also be EOT.

Comment: I did notice the missing ```g``` in ```My text is so interesting, depending "interestin``` and the missing starting ```i``` in ```nteresting, depending "interesting" meaning of course.``` in your original post. Since you hadn't specifically mentioned that they are necessary to be like that, I went ahead and posted my answer.